# Transfer the working code from the Main to the method for TowerBuilder in C#

Tags: c#

I have following code, which according to the input parameter nFloors (number of floors) when run in `Main()` creates a tree of `*`.  For example:

```
int nFloors=6;
int blank=nFloors*2-1;
for(int j=1;j<nFloors*2;j+=2)
     Console.WriteLine(((new string(' ', (blank-j)/2))+(new string('*', j)))+(new string(' ', (blank-j)/2)));
```

Output:

```
     *     
    ***    
   *****   
  *******  
 ********* 
***********
```

Now I want to transfer that code in a separate method:

```
public static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
  {
    return new string[0];
  }
```

This method should return an array instead of printing it to Console. I tried this but that does not produce wanted output:

```
public static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
{
     int blank=nFloors*2-1;
     string [] array=new string[nFloors] ; //declare an array to be returned with
                                           //nFloors elements inside
     
     int j;
     for(j=0;j<nFloors;j+=2) //array should be looped from 0, but if in that way
                             // we get even j values (0,2,4..) and j needs to be odd
                             // (1,3,5..)
     array[j]=(((new string(' ', (blank-j)/2))+(new string('*', j)))+(new string(' ', (blank-j)/2)));
        
     return array;   

      }
```

The issue here is how to loop an array getting the odd values of j (odd values correspond to number of `*`) while correctly accessing array elements (from first to last element i.e. `j<nFloors`). I believe it is a trivial thing but I can't figure it out. Tried researching similar issues but with no results.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid complicated indexing issues, I'd just add to a list instead:

```
public static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
{
     int blank = nFloors*2-1;
     var list= new List<string>();
     
     for(int j = 1; j < nFloors*2; j += 2)
     {
         list.Add(((new string(' ', (blank-j)/2))+(new string('*', j)))+(new string(' ', (blank-j)/2)));
     }
        
     return list.ToArray();   
}
```

If you insist on using an array, then you basically need a function that maps the interval [0..nFloors] => Odd Numbers.

For example : f(x) = 2*x+1
which gives you

```
0 => 1
1 => 3
2 => 5
...
```

---

Unrelated: I think the last `+(new string(' ', (blank-j)/2))` may be not neccessary? It's just trailing blanks ...

Comment: Thanks! It seems that you are right about that as well, now it is a mystery to me how the blanks are symmetrically dispersed on both left and right side without that.

Comment: @user749827 for screen layout, just the leading characters count (as long as the total length is less than the screen length). The trailing spaces are there in your original, you just don't see them (try replacing with a `.`)

Comment: Right, just the left blanks count, good thinking.

Answer (score 0):

(Good answer supplied w using list, here is an option if using array is required)

You should use different variables to keep track of the array index v/s the number of stars and blanks. This should work:

```
static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
{
     int blank=nFloors*2-1;
     string [] array=new string[nFloors] ; 
     for(int j=0;j<nFloors;j+=1){ 
        int stars = (j*2)+1;
        array[j]=(((new string(' ', (blank-stars)/2))+(new string('*', stars)))+(new string(' ', (blank-stars)/2)));
     }
     return array;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With meaning-full variables names, [some coding convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) (no type prefixed variables name) and good use of [nice C# feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) the code may looks like a readable thing:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> BuildTower(int floorCount)
{
    var towerWidth = floorCount * 2 - 1;
    for (var floor = 0; floor < floorCount; floor++)
    {
        var starCount = floor * 2 + 1;
        var blankCount = (towerWidth - starCount) / 2;

        var stars = new string('*', starCount);
        var blanks = new string(' ', blankCount);

        yield return blanks + stars + blanks;
    }
}
```